# Retrieving the Post Request response and storing into a variable in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I am using the [Face Recognition and Face Detection](https://rapidapi.com/lambda/api/face-recognition-and-face-detection?endpoint=53aa3243e4b07e1f4ebe9bb3) api by lambda and am supposed to get a response from the api using post. Usually for getting responses I use get while for sending responses I use post. How do I get this response using post so I can tell whether the image has been recognized or not? 
My code is below:

**Node.js file**

```
facedetAPIRoutes.route("/").post(function (req, res){
    let imageUrl = req.body.url;
    myFaceDetAPI.recognizeImg(imageUrl);
});
```

**Service file**

```
sendImage(imgUrl){
    console.log(imgUrl);
    const obj = {
      url: imgUrl
    };    

    this.http.post(`${this.uri}`, obj)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log("this is res: " + res);
        console.log('image sent to api done');
      });
  }
```

**Component file**

```
public handleImage(webcamImage: WebcamImage): void {
    console.info("received webcam image", webcamImage);
    this.webcamImage = webcamImage;
    console.log("this is: " + this.webcamImage.imageAsDataUrl);
    //this.fda.sendImage(this.webcamImage.imageAsDataUrl);
    this.fda.sendImage("http://localhost:4000/uploads/1570563000257-arnold4.jpg");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a problem in my backend file. For this I simply used res.status. That way I was able to use subscribe in my service file.

**Node.js**

```
facedetAPIRoutes.route("/").post(function (req, res){
    let imageUrl = req.body.url;
    res.status(200).json(myFaceDetAPI.recognizeImg(imageUrl));
});
```

**Service File**

```
 sendImage(imgUrl){
    console.log(imgUrl);
    const obj = {
      url: imgUrl
    };    

    this.http.post(`${this.uri}`, obj)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log("this is res: " + JSON.stringify(res));
        console.log('image sent to api done');
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hellow. You can use STATUS CODE of response. 200 status code is success status for operation.
or if error it sent you status code 4xx.
You can read more about status code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Thanks you Anton. The link helped

Comment: You are welcome. Can you mark my post, as the best answer.Thanks